# Cross-Site Scripting: encodeForHTML for HTML content (The OWASP Enterprise Security API)

Tags: javascript, jsp, xss, owasp, cross-site

I have a HTML select Tag in my JSP

```
<%@ taglib prefix="esapi"   uri="http://www.owasp.org/index.php/Category:OWASP_Enterprise_Security_API"%>

    <select>
       ...
      <option value="volvo">${device.name}</option>
      ....
    </select>
```

I set this as device name in the DB

```
"><script>alert(1)</script>2d65
```

I've tried to get rid of the alert when I load the page using

```
<esapi:encodeForHTMLAttribute>${device.name}</esapi:encodeForHTMLAttribute>
```

or

```
<esapi:encodeForHTML>${device.name}</esapi:encodeForHTML>
```

or

```
<c : out value="${device.name}"/>
```

or

```
 <esapi:encodeForJavaScript>${device.name}</esapi:encodeForJavaScript>
```

But there is no way ! The alert message always appears when loading the page !

In fact, I see that the characters are escaped, but even that an alert appears in the JSP

[image]

Comment: It looks like esapi has not encoded the parameter. Have you checked the generated html?

Comment: can you show full related code , and generated Html please ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try without the taglib:

```
 <%@ page import="org.owasp.esapi.*" %>

 ...
 <select>
   ...
  <option value="volvo"><%out.print(ESAPI.encoder().encodeForHTML(device.name));%></option>
  ....
 </select>
```

Comment: I'm having the same issue and applied the above solution. It is throwing an error saying _device_ cannot be resolved to a variable (* Used device to be in sync with the above example)